# Use start up command line to change file location

Tags: command-line, startup-file

I am currenlty using a .bat file to start Blender, with this

```
set PYTHONPATH=
"%~dp0\blender"
```

So that I can use the local Python folder.

Is there a way to tell Blender to look for a file in a different location?

For example of I wanted to setup a default start file to be on the `D:\custom location` rather than `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\config`